# CSS with JSF and Primefaces - styleClass does not change the font size

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Someone can tell me why the selectOneMenu, InputMask, inputText not handle font size, width e height defined in the class of my css file? Only takes when using the style = "font-size: 11px;".

xhtml:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.parametro.numTipoAcesso}" styleClass="selectOneMenu">
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />                     
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Acesso Básico" itemValue="1" />
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Acesso Múltiplo DDR" itemValue="2" />
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="CNG" itemValue="3" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:inputText id="numeroBilhete" styleClass="inputText" value="#{bean.parametro.numBilhetePortabilidade}" disabled="#{bean.parametro.fraude == false}"/>

<p:inputMask id="identidade" styleClass="inputText" value="#{bean.parametro.identidade}" mask="99999999-9" disabled="#{bean.parametro.naoPossuiId == true}" required="true" requiredMessage="Digite o Documento de Identidade." />
```

css

```
.selectOneMenu {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    width   : 193px; 
    height  : 23px; 
}

.inputText {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    width   : 186px; 
    height  : 20px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Globally changing font size in Primefaces http://stackoverflow.com/a/9154248/617373

Comment: maybe your css file is not loaded into the browser...

Answer (score 1):

So with PF 3.5RC1 this works (attribute style, intention is to color the text inside inputMask in grey):

```
<p:inputMask id="iDatum" value="#{referenz.verkehrstagReferenz}" mask="99.99.99" converter="#{verkehrstagBOConverter}" 
                            disabled="#{referenz.referenzTyp.toString() == 'IST'}" style="#{referenz.displayed ? '' : 'color: #808080'}" size="8">
                            <p:ajax event="blur" update="@form" process="@form" />
                        </p:inputMask>
```

But this won't work (attribute styleClass):

```
<p:inputMask id="iDatum" value="#{referenz.verkehrstagReferenz}" mask="99.99.99" converter="#{verkehrstagBOConverter}" 
                            disabled="#{referenz.referenzTyp.toString() == 'IST'}" styleClass="#{referenz.displayed ? '' : 'grey'}" size="8">
                            <p:ajax event="blur" update="@form" process="@form" />
                        </p:inputMask>
```